# How do gods/devatas procreate?

Tags: puranas, gods, sex

I have found people claiming that gods do not procreate like humans but procreate without any bodily union on Quora, does this idea have scriptural backing?

Comment: Actually rivers, mountains, planets, stars, earth, winds etc are the real *deva*-s who live in higher plane of existence. Human being like gods shown in TV/films is either fantasy or represntation. Unfortunately I don't have any solid scripture but only indirect references. They do have ability to take human form & procreate with humans. The scripture based example is of Kunti & Madri begetting Pandava-s. [See here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01124.htm).

Comment: I agree. Anthropomophric representations are just to help us humans understand them better, but I get this from logic, not scripture.

Comment: yes. Kunti getting son (karna) from Surya deva with help of mantra chanting is an example of non-human progeny. Sanskrit verse "yonir yatha na dushyetha'. Parvati devi has cursed devas that no procreation is possible in deva loka, so either god or goddess has to come down to earth for getting progeny

Comment: @ram do you have a reference of Parvati's curse?

Comment: If you go by Veda, which is the basis for subsequent literature  in India,  God is formless.   Depicting God in human form was to make humans with ordinary intelligence understand the spiritual concepts. @Anisha

Comment: https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13b050.htm seems to be useful..

Comment: @iammilind (Another annoying years late reply here) but what you wrote above re the rivers, mountains, planets, stars, earth, etc, I think that is def accurate however I also wonder if that is partial info; that along w/ that there are also higher level devas that are existing too. I think reality at higher planes of existence is more complicated (and wonderful in many ways) than what we think we can see from a lower level of understanding. Same for reality at this plane of existence  ! :D

Answer (score 4):

Fifteen years after the Mahabharata war, Kunti, Gandhari, Dhritarashtra, and Vidura leave Hastinapura to retire in the woods. Maharshi Veda Vyasa meets Kunti who tells him that she is desperate to see Karna who was killed in battle.

Vyasa explained how the gods are able to produce offspring when Kunti blamed herself for what happened to Karna.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m15/m15030.htm

> Thus addressed by Kunti, Vyasa, that foremost of all persons, said unto her in reply,--'Blessed be thou; all that thou hast said unto me will happen. (As regards the birth of Karna) no fault is ascribable to thee. Thou wert restored to virginity. The deities are possessed of (Yoga) puissance.
>
> They are able to penetrate human bodies.There are deities.They beget (offspring) by **thought** alone. **By word, by sight, by touch, and by sexual union, also, they beget children. These are the five methods.**

Answer (score 1):

The notion that Gods cannot procreate through their respective wives, might have emanated from the episode from Bala Kanda of Ramayana, wherein [Uma, the consort of Shiva, curses so](https://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga36/bala_36_frame.htm).

> यस्मान्निवारिता चाहं संगता पुत्रकाम्यया || १-३६-२१ अपत्यं स्वेषु
>   दारेषु नोत्पादयितुमर्हथ |
>
> " 'Wherefore, I who am desirous of a son had been prevented from the
>   intimacy with my husband, therefore you shall be ***infecund to beget
>   progeny through your own wives***. "
>
> अद्य प्रभृति युष्माकमप्रजाः सन्तु पत्नयः || १-३६-२२ एवमुक्त्वा
>   सुरान्सर्वान् शशाप पृथिवीमपि |
>
> " '***And from now onwards you wives shall remain infertile***...' and on
>   saying this way to all of the gods she also gave a curse to the
>   earth."

---

We have to remember the following issues:

1) Much before Ramayana was composed, Rig Veda contained verses indicating Maruts as the sons of [Rudra and Pṛśni](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06066.htm).

> They who are ***Sons of the rain-pouring Rudra***, whom the long-lasting One
>   had power to foster: The Mighty Ones whose germ great ***Mother Pṛśni*** is
>   known to have received for man's advantage.

So the story of Uma cursing Gods might be an interpolated story.

2) The God is only ONE and formless.  Most of stories that were described in Literature about children of God are epithets only, but should not be taken literally.

Comment: your most of the answers r based on the *interpolation* which cannot be proved so easily. how u can label something interpolated without proper proof? in above answer, if gods had children before this curse then how this became interpolated? even after this curse, if some god got children then we must search for the reason how they got that exception instead of just labeling a story interpolated, it's also possible that getting children from their wife is interpolated instead of a's curse..

Comment: I have expressed my opinion, based on my analysis for which I had quoted scriptural base.  Whether to accept it or not,  rests with the reader.  @YDS

Comment: Whoever down voted my answer should be courageous enough to state the reasons. Otherwise it tells upon their cowardice only.

Comment: There is no cowardice . Some may agree with @YDS line of thinking.