# How do gods like Shiva procreate? Do gods do sex like humans?

Tags: gods, sex

I have found people claiming that gods do not procreate like humans but procreate without any bodily union on Quora, does this idea have scriptural backing?

I thick virya(or)teja means fire spirit in the case of devatas.
For example :

Kumarasambavam(birth of kumaraswamy according to Mahabharata,skanda Purana,shiva purana,Ramayana.:

Story tells that

1)lord Shiva and Lord pravati make sex many 100 years . [ how it is possible]. I thick it is tapa.

2)Agni Deva Drunk semen of lord Shiva.[ what this is idiotic ]. I thick Shiva virya is fire spirit for that Agni Deva merge  the great fire spirit .

3)Agni Deva discharge Shiva virya to ganga Devi [ how can Agni discharge Shiva virya ].I thick agni un-merge Shiva virya and gives to ganga devi.

**my main question do any script tell devatas procreate like human**

Do not tell this is duplicate question .
In that question no one answer rightly.

Comment: Sex in not satvik. All Gods are satvik. So no God have sex with a goddess.

Comment: Lord shiva have sex with Pravati

Comment: @Dark-knight Indra have sex with apsaras . lord Shiva have sex with pravati it is mentioned in Shiva Purana,Ramayana,Skanda Purana,Mahabharata.

Comment: This is a dup of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27868/how-do-gods-devatas-procreate also the first line has been has been lifted 'as is' from the other question. Why are you copying and asking the same question again?

Comment: @sv. Why are you not casting dupe vote? :-)

Comment: It won't let me close as dup since there is not a single upvoted answer. Time to use your supervote :) @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @SV for first question do not have any answer

Comment: By closing. We can not get right answer

Comment: Do you know how [bounty](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) works? You can start a bounty on the other question by copying the entire content of this question as bounty reason and still get answers to the other question. You don't need to create new Q's on the same topic if the original Q doesn't have good answers.